# Confused what to do with this public void addRating method?

Tags: java, methods

I'm very new to coding, and one of my projects was to create two books with a name, author, title and etc. The problem is when I need to give each book at least random 5 ratings (0-5 stars) using the add rating method provided by the class(the first set of code). I'm not sure how to approach this to give each book a rating. Of course, the first book (book1) is a default constructor, so (book2) is the one that needs the random ratings.

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int numPages;
    private double avgRating;
    private int ratingCount;
    
    /*
    *Creates a book with default values
    */
    public Book(){
        title = "Something";
        author = "Anonymous";
        numPages = 1000;
        avgRating = 1.0;
        ratingCount = 1;
    }
    
    /*
    *Creates a book with the given values
    *parameter bTitle - title of the book
    *parameter bAuthor - author of the book
    *parameter pages - how many pages are in the book
    *parameter bRating - the book's average rating, out of 5 stars
    *parameter rCount - how many ratings the book has
    */
    public Book(String bTitle, String bAuthor, int pages, double bRating, int rCount) {
        title = bTitle;
        author = bAuthor;
        numPages = pages;
        avgRating = bRating;
        ratingCount = rCount;
    }
    
    /*
    *returns the author of this book as a String
    */
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    
    /*
    *returns the title of this book as a String
    */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
        
    /*
    *returns the pages of this book as an int
    */
    public int getPages() {
        return numPages;
    }
    
    /*
    *returns the rating of this book as a double
    */
    public double getRating() {
        return avgRating;
    }
    
    public int getRatingCount() {
      return ratingCount;
    }


    public void addRating(int stars){
        //calculate total of all ratings
        double total= avgRating * ratingCount;
        //increase number of ratings to include this new one
        ratingCount++;
        //add this rating to the total of all ratings
        total += stars;
        //recalculate average
        avgRating = total / ratingCount;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project2{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   
      /*
      *Asks the user for title of the book
      *Asks the user for author of the book
      *Asks the user for the number of pages of the book
      */
      Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
   
      System.out.print("Give the title of a book: ");
      String title = type.nextLine();
     
      System.out.print("Enter the author of " + title + ": ");
      String author = type.nextLine();
   
      System.out.print("Enter the number of pages in " + title +": ");
      int numPages = type.nextInt();
     
     

      
      Book book1 = new Book();
     
      Book book2 = new Book(title, author, numPages, avgRating, ratingcount);

     
      //Combines both The last letter of each book's title//
     
      int totalCharacter = book1.getTitle().length() + book2.getTitle().length();
     
     
      System.out.println("Book1 title is: " + book1.getTitle() + "." + " It was written by " + book1.getAuthor() + " and has " + book1.getPages() + " pages." + " After " + book1.getRatingCount() + " ratings, this book got a rating of " + book1.getRating()+ ".");
      System.out.println("Book2 title is: " + book2.getTitle() + "." + " It was written by " + book2.getAuthor() + " and has " + book2.getPages() + " pages." + " After " + book2.getRatingCount() + " ratings, this book got a rating of " + book2.getRating()+ ".");
      System.out.println("The total number of characters in both books title is: " + totalCharacter);
      System.out.println("The first letter of each author's name, concatenated together is: " + book1.getAuthor().substring(0,1) + book2.getAuthor().substring(0,1));
      System.out.println("The last letter of each book's title, concatenated together is: " + book1.getTitle().substring(book1.getTitle().length()-1) + book2.getTitle().substring(book2.getTitle().length()-1));
     
     
     
   }
}
```

Comment: cant you do this with for loop?

Comment: You have compilation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Book book2 = new Book(title, author, numPages, avgRating, ratingcount);
```

You are using variables that are not declared. `avgRating, ratingCount`. Declare them first. If you want to give some *random* rating you can use `Math.random()` method which gives a random `double` between 0 and 1. Multiply it with a number to get your desired rating .

While creating the book, you give only *initial* rating (values). Every book is created with an initial rating as mentioned in your default constructor.

When creating a book with the second constructor, you can pass in the values which are put as in your default constructor itself.

```
  Book book2 = new Book(title, author, numPages, 1.0, 1);
```

or some other values of your choice.

You add a rating after creating the book for which you have the `addRating()` method that lets you add your ratings that will automatically calculate the average rating of your book.

```
book1.addRating(4);
book2.addRating(5);
```

Moreover, you should also write a `getAvgRating()` method that returns the `avgRating`

Comment: Thank You so much! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Math.random() would be the easiest way to get the random numbers (can be done within a range as well)
2. Define and utilize the variables needed accordingly or else will end up in null exception